# Which is more pythonic for array removal?

Tags: python

I'm removing an item from an array if it exists.

Two ways I can think of to do this

### Way #1

```
# x array, r item to remove
if r in x :
  x.remove( r )
```

### Way #2

```
try :
  x.remove( r )
except :
  pass
```

Timing it shows the try/except way **can be** faster

(some times i'm getting:)

```
1.16225508968e-06
8.80804972547e-07

1.14314196588e-06
8.73752536492e-07
```

```
import timeit

runs = 10000
x = [ '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', 'a', 'b', 'c',
  'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', '111', '112', '113',
  'x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'wwwwwww', 'aeiojwaef', 'iweojfoigj', 'oiowow',
  'oiweoiwioeiowe', 'oiwjaoigjoaigjaowig',
]
r = 'a'

code1 ="""
x = [ '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', 'a', 'b', 'c',
  'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', '111', '112', '113',
  'x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'wwwwwww', 'aeiojwaef', 'iweojfoigj', 'oiowow',
  'oiweoiwioeiowe', 'oiwjaoigjoaigjaowig',
]
r = 'a'

if r in x :
  x.remove(r)
"""
print timeit.Timer( code1 ).timeit( runs ) / runs

code2 ="""
x = [ '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', 'a', 'b', 'c',
  'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', '111', '112', '113',
  'x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'wwwwwww', 'aeiojwaef', 'iweojfoigj', 'oiowow',
  'oiweoiwioeiowe', 'oiwjaoigjoaigjaowig',
]
r = 'a'

try :
  x.remove( r )
except :
  pass
"""
print timeit.Timer( code2 ).timeit( runs ) / runs
```

Which is more pythonic?

Comment: This seems inherently subjective to me.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Your sample results are nowhere near 10x different. More like 1.3x different.

Comment: Your cost suggests a reasonable expectation that r might not be in x.  You need to time the case where r is not in x so that the exception is actually raised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've always gone with the first method.  `if in` reads far more clearly than exception handling does.

Comment: To all who are downvoting, please understand that the OP asked for the 'most pythonic' way, not the 'most efficient'.

Answer (score 5):

that would be:

```
try:
  x.remove(r)
except ValueError:
  pass
```

btw, you should have tried to remove an item that is not in the list, to have a comprehensive comparison.

Comment: Why do you think this is clearer (the most import ingredient in being pythonic).

Comment: Because it's easier to ask forgiveness than to get permission. Your definition is too rather subjective

Answer (score 3):

Speed depends on the ratio of hits to misses. To be pythonic choose the clearer method.

Personally I think way#1 is clearer (It takes less lines to have an 'if' block rather than an exception block and also uses less brain space). It will also be faster when there are more hits than misses (an exception is more expensive than skipping a if block).

Answer (score 2):

The try/except way

Answer (score 1):

The first way looks cleaner.  The second looks like a lot of extra effort just to remove an item from a list.

There's nothing about it in [PEP-8](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), though, so whichever you prefer is the 'real' answer.

Speaking of PEP-8... having that space before the colon falls under the definition of 'extraneous whitespace'.